# Прямоугольная трапеция div

Tags: css3, canvas, html, веб-дизайн, html5

Как сделать прямоугольную трапецию из одного **div**. Не из двух (треугольник + прямоугольник), а сразу с одного. Можно сделать трапецию равнобедренную, так не сойдет. Нужно именно [Пример](http://s006.radikal.ru/i215/1212/b7/93a709f87b80.png). Потому что внутри я хочу заполнить текстом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#trapezoid {
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
#trapezoid span {
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id='trapezoid'><span>Текст</span></div>
```

Comment: Вообще не то, на прямоугольную трапецию не похожа.На speech-bubble похожа

Comment: @Ruzel да вы что? http://goo.gl/buPHF

Comment: Извените, мне вот такая вот нужна 
http://goo.gl/Uc6IZ

Comment: @Ruzel обновил пост.

Comment: Спасибо на этом) А как сделать чтоб текст по наклонной облегал с внутри. А то текст все равно в прямоугольный блок заполняется.

Comment: @Ruzel я пока не вижу только так: несколько тегов (каждый тег на новой строке), и у каждого тега разная длина отступа.