# Как можно сделать скос у блока?

Tags: html, css3

У меня есть `div`, с такими стилями

```
<style>
      width: 1401px;
      height: 1654px;
      object-fit: contain;
      background-color: #50cd0a;
</style>
```

Нужно сделать такой же скос у низа блока, как и на изображении.
 Какими способами это можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/171115/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 1654px;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: #50cd0a;
  position: relative;
}

section:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 100px 100vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```