# Форма блока div html/css

Tags: html, css, jsx

можно ли как-то сделать блок div примерно такой же формы как нарисовано на картинке ниже, либо же сделать это каким-либо еще тегом кроме div[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/171115/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[это вам на помощь](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

вы должны создать див и через css дать свойство который генерируется на сайте